# The meaning of "by so" in the sentence

Tags: prepositions

Here is the sentence:

> A person who agrees to serve as mediator between two warring factions
>   at the request of both abandons by so agreeing the right to take sides
>   later. To take sides at a later point would be to suggest that the
>   earlier presumptive impartiality was a sham.

I don't understand the meaning of "by so" in this sentences. Does the sentence mean "by abandoning agreeing the right to take sides later, a person can become a mediator", or "by serving as mediator, a person must abandon taking sides later"? What does the "so" refer to?  And is "by so" a "adverbial modifier" of "abandon agreeing"?

Comment: by so agreeing = by making this agreement // _by so agreeing_ is an adverbial modifying _abandons_ (the option of taking sides later on).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=so&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=AFJ9UdO-I6TW2QWlg4C4Cg&ved=0CDQQkQ4&biw=1333&bih=851 (so: "in the way described or demonstrated; thus")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's parsed: [by][so agreeing] instead of [by so][agreeing]

The essence of the sentence is:

A person who agrees to serve, abandons (gives up) the right to take sides.

You can substitute
"*by agreeing in this way*" for "*by so agreeing*":

> A person who agrees to serve as mediator between two warring factions at the request of both, abandons (*by agreeing in this way*) the right to take sides later.